# Invalid "--android-sdk" value "C:\android-sdk-win" in Titanium while deploying app on android mobile

Tags: android, eclipse, titanium-alloy

I'm working on Titanium with alloy framework and quit new in it. I have develop some simple apps and these are working fine on my laptop's browser.Now i want to test it on my android mobile but unable to deploy it on my device. I've installed device driver on system and connected device on debugging mode but when i try to run as android device in titanium , i get Invalid "--android-sdk" value "C:\android-sdk-win" error. while ni case of native android apps (with java/eclipse) my device is working fine and I'm able to test my apps on my mobile in debugging mode. Don't know what is the problem with Titanium. I've searched internet for this problem but couldn't find any good solution. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you don't have any SDK in "C:\android-sdk-win".

You should ensure you have the correct Android SDK/NDK paths configured in Titanium:Preferences:Studio:Platforms:Android.

Comment: Thanks #csg for your response. I've checked the path for sdk is correct and mentioned there but there is no path for NDK , what does it means and what is NDK and for what NDK is used?

Comment: The path is usually C:\Users\YOURUSER\Documents\Android\ndk\android-ndk-r8d

Comment: Solved. The problem was the Android Versions (in titanium and installed in device) was different. The version on device was 4.4 while android version installed on titanium was 5.0. I've installed same android version in titanium and it worked. however android with java doesn't required same version on eclipse and device thats why I ignored this thing before. Anyways Thanks for you help csg.